# how to return all file names from 1 folder, if files match to another folder?

Tags: python

**Variables**

```
first= 'C:/Users/shady/Desktop/test folder/check'

second = 'C:/Users/shady/Desktop/test folder/checked'
```

Inside `first` there is a file name named

`test 1 ed.docx`

&

Inside `second` there is a **similar** file name with a **different extension** along with an extra file:

`test 1.jpg`

`test 2.jpg`

**Question**

By looking on my code, I need to set `choices` to return me **all files** from `second`, but if the two folders have similar file names (not including the extension **but including `ed`**) then do not show that file name.

**My current Code**

```
import os
import glob


first= 'C:/Users/shady/Desktop/test folder/check'

second = 'C:/Users/shady/Desktop/test folder/checked'

choices = os.listdir(second)
print(choices)
```

**Current output**

```
['test 1.jpg', 'test 2.jpg']
```

**Desired output**

```
['test 2.jpg']
```

This is the output, because the file name (`test 2 ed.docx`) does not exist inside `first`.

And

`test 1.jpg` exists in `first` becasue `test 1 ed.docx` are a good match.

This is where I got to:

```
import os

Username = "ed"

first = 'C:/Users/shady/Desktop/test folder/check/'
second = 'C:/Users/shady/Desktop/test folder/checked/'

choices = os.listdir(second)

list = []
for x in choices:
    x = (x.strip('.JPG') + ' ' + Username + '.docx')
```

but not sure if this is the correct direction im heading to with this code..

Comment: You should significantly rephrase the question to make it concise and clear. As I understood, you need to match begin of the file names excluding the extensions, which can be done using `purename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]` and `purename.startswith(purename2)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but how do I include the username too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os

Username = "ed"

first = 'C:/Users/shady/Desktop/test folder/check/'
second = 'C:/Users/shady/Desktop/test folder/checked/'


one = [f for f in os.listdir(first) if isfile(join(first, f))]
two = [f for f in os.listdir(second) if isfile(join(second, f))]


for x in [one]:
    x1 = [y.rstrip(' ' + Username + '.docx')+'.jpg' for y in x]
    choices = (set(two).difference(x1)) # returns all files that are not the same based on 'x1'
```

Comment: what is going on inside `one` & `two`? What was the point in that? But the code works perfect!

Comment: @Valuez it puts all the file names into a list